# ColdFusion 11 CFChart issue

Tags: coldfusion-11

Gah...this upgrade to ColdFusion 11 continues to give me massive headaches!!! I encountered a couple of issues today with CFChart.

First...I used to be able to have the $$ variables in lower case..that no longer works. The documentation says camelCase works, but that still produced an error. Upper case though, thankfully, works.

Second, the values in the $$ variables seem to have gotten all screwed up...
I had this code in CF10 (and CF9, CF8 etc....)

```
    <cfchart  format="#myformat#" 
        chartheight="350" 
        chartwidth="600"  
        show3d="yes" 
        showlegend="yes"
        pieslicestyle="sliced"
        xaxistitle="RELATED_TO"
        yaxistitle="NBR"
        url="chart_rpt.cfm?value=$value$&item=$itemlabel$&series=$serieslabel$&rptpd=#rptpd#&rpttype=#rptval#"> 
    <cfchartseries 
      type="pie"
      query="appdata" 
      itemcolumn="related_to" 
      valuecolumn="nbr"
      serieslabel="Type"
      > 
  </cfchartseries>          
  </cfchart>
```

I had to change this to (charts look identical, by the by...):

```
    <cfchart  format="#myformat#" 
        chartheight="350" 
        chartwidth="600"  
        show3d="yes" 
        showlegend="yes"
        pieslicestyle="sliced"
        xaxistitle="RELATED_TO"
        yaxistitle="NBR"
        url="chart_rpt.cfm?value=$VALUE$&item=$SERIESLABEL$&series=$ITEMLABEL$&rptpd=#rptpd#&rpttype=#rptval#" > 
    <cfchartseries 
      type="pie"
      query="appdata" 
      itemcolumn="related_to" 
      valuecolumn="nbr"
      serieslabel="Type"
      > 
  </cfchartseries>          
  </cfchart>
```

Note the change in the url clause: The value in $SERIESLABEL$ should be 'Type'...instead its 'Foreign'. The value in $ITEMLABEL$ should be 'Foreign' but instead is 'Type'. I had to switch the $$ variables around for the chart_rpt.cfm routine to produce the expected data.

Did they change the definitions of these $$ variables? Is anyone else having these issues?

Comment: not sure if this make a difference but did you try camel-case for attribute 'seriesLabel ="Type"' ?

Comment: and you don't need closing tag for <cfchartseries> instead you can do it inside one tag for example:<cfchartseries
                 type="pie" seriesLabel="Type"
                 query="appdata"
                 itemcolumn="related_to"
                 valuecolumn="nbr"
                />}

Comment: Silly question, but could it have anything to do with the fact that the assignments of the url variables seem to be reversed? ie You are using SERIESLABEL for `item` and `ITEMLABEL` for `series`.

Comment: @Leigh...if you notice in the original (the top code block), they were the other way around..its only in the CF11 version where I have to change them to get the correct values in the called routine. We have only have two places where this is true, so I am commenting the code and moving on.

Comment: @Casuzen - My bad. I missed that. I cannot test it under CF11, but if you can put together a stand-alone repro case demonstrating the issue between CF10 and CF11, you should [file a bug report](https://bugbase.adobe.com). Then post it back here.